# How to wait for an async method to be completed in a background tast

Tags: java, asynchronous, download, task, wait

Implementing a backgroung task to fetch to checksum on a remote server and to update the live tile accordingly, I've bumped into a timing issue.

Here's the code :

```
        MatchListImpl.IsThereNewResults();
        NewsListImpl.IsThereNewNews();

        RaiseToast();
        UpdateTile();
```

It's rather simple.
The first two calls are refering to *async* function that will download two files "*.cksum" using a WebConnector. The last two calls will update the tile and raise notification depending on the content of the downloaded files.

The problem is that the later function are often executed before the two files are downloaded, the *async* method not being completed. And of course, the whole logic of the thing is void.

My question is : Is there a way to "pause" the execution of the task to really wait for the *async* method to be over ?

As this is absolutely unelegant, second question : Is there not a better way of doing this ?

Thanks for yours answers :)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass your current class to async task and then in the onPostExecute method of your async class call    RaiseToast() and UpdateTile() for example: assuming that in RaiseToast() you are using some files that are downloaded in  MatchListImpl async task , you can pass current class that RaiseToast() is in ther to async task class ,  in it's constructor.

```
class MatchListImpl extends AsyncTask{
    ClassContainingRaiseToast myClass;
    //contructor:
    MatchListImpl(ClassContainingRaiseToast myClass){
    this.myClass = myClass;
    }
    ... 
    @Override
    //this method will be executed after finishing AsyncTask job
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
          // RaiseToast() must be declared public in myClass
             myClass.RaiseToast();
    }

}
```

so don't call RaiseToast() in myClass itself. and call it in asyncTast class istead!